# MFC: How to get default button of child dialog to work?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, childwindow, defaultbutton

I have a child dialog which I created as a new dialog in the resource editor.  Then I used a static control on the parent dialog to act as a placeholder.  The child control is displayed where the place holder is using the following code:

```
CRect rect;
m_optionPanelPlaceholder.GetWindowRect(&rect); // In screen coordinates
ScreenToClient(&rect);
m_optionPanelPlaceholder.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

optionsDialogPanel_ = new OptionsDialogPanel(settings_);
// Call Create() explicitly to ensure the HWND is created.
optionsDialogPanel_->Create(OptionsDialogPanel::IDD, this);

// Set the window position to be where the placeholder was.
optionsDialogPanel_->SetWindowPos
    (
    NULL,
    rect.left,
    rect.top,
    rect.Width(),
    rect.Height(),
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW
    );
```

This all works fine.  There is a button on my child dialog which is set as the default button.  Clicking the button with the mouse takes the desired action.  However I want to just press the Enter key while in any of the edit text boxes on the child dialog and have the default button's action taken.   However it's not working; how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your button has its ID set to **IDOK** and not some IDC_***. MFC takes care of the rest!

Answer (score 0):

When hitting the enter button in a dialog, the Parent::OnOK method is called. So you can probably call the Child::OnOK inside Parent::OnOK method.

Thanks.